# Java, subprocesses and unread output streams: When does it deadlock?

Tags: java, process, deadlock, block

When creating sub-processes in java using `Runtime.exec()`, I am aware that I have to fill the input/drain the output streams to prevent blocking of the subprocess.

Interestingly, the javadoc of `Process` states a little bit more:

```
...failure to promptly write the input stream or read the output stream of
the subprocess may cause the subprocess to block, and even deadlock.
```

I am wondering that in this situation the subprocess can  **also deadlock**!

**Questions:**
1. Under which conditions does it deadlock? 
2. Why does it deadlock?
3. Can you provide a short example program which shows this deadlock?
4. Is this deadlock a bug in the OS?

Comment: +1... *(not an answer to your question hence the comment)*...  Note that a long time ago (when I read *"When Runtime.exec won't"* IIRC), I decided to dodge that issue entirely by immediately forking/exiting from the Runtime.exec'ed shell script and redirect any output from the second shell script to temporary files (and then parse these temporary files from Java).  It's brutal but it works (I've done it on both Linux and OS X... Don't know about Windows)  : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deadlock can occur due to limited buffer sizes when the parent tries to send too much data to the input stream of its child before reading any of the output.

Consider this code:

```
final int LINES = 10;
// "tr" is a Unix command that translates characters;
// Here, for every line it reads, it will output a line with
// every 'a' character converted to 'A'.  But any command that outputs
// something for every line it reads (like 'cat') will work here
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tr a A");
Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream());
for (int i = 0; i < LINES; i++) {
    out.write("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\n");
}
out.close();
// Read all the output from the process and write it to stdout
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

For small values for `lines`, it will work fine; all of `tr`'s output can fit in the OS buffer before we start reading it.  However, for large values (>10000 ought to be sufficient), the OS buffer will fill up; within the `tr` command, calls to `write` will block, waiting for the buffer to be drained, and in turn, the buffer that the Java code is writing to will fill up (because `tr` is be blocked, preventing it from reading from its input), in turn blocking *our* calls to `out.write`, leading to a deadlock where both processes are waiting to write into full buffers that aren't being actively read from.

This deadlock is not a bug in the OS, as limited buffer sizes for inter-process communication are a deliberate design decision.  The alternative (unlimited buffer sizes) has some downsides:

- Can exhaust kernel memory
- To avoid the above, if buffers automatically "spill over" to disk, that can lead to unpredictable performance and can potentially fill up the disk.

---

As an aside, deadlock can also occur due to in-process buffers.  Suppose that, to attempt to address the deadlock above, we changed our Java code to write one line, then read one line, alternatingly.  However, [it's common for Linux processes to not flush after every line when they're not writing directly to a terminal](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/).  So `tr` might read a line, and write it to its libc output buffer, and than block waiting for the next line to be written--and our Java code will block waiting for `tr` to output a line.

Answer (score 1):

Deadlock involves always at least 2 participants. So it's not the subprocess alone that may dead lock, but the combination of the parent process and the subprocess.

For an example:

Subprocess wants to read a line, process it and print the result.
Parent process thinks it can read output from the subprocess first, and only then provide input to it.

Result: deadlock, both processes are waiting for input from the other.

And, hence, no, it's not a bug in the OS but a logical error in the (parent) process.

Comment: I'm not sure if this kind of issue is intended by the javadoc - the issue that you are describing is a general synchronization problem in concurrent environments but has nothing to do with java/Process class in particular. The javadoc also states that this only happens "on some native platforms [which] only provide limited buffer size", while the situation you describe will block on all OS.

Comment: @MRalwaser - if this is so then I would indeed consider it a bug in the OS. The more so as "promptly" is a bit unspecific. As long as the communication is done in the right order it should not matter whether I do it "promptly" or 2 days later.